# Graphing a non function derivative

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I'm in the midst of a graphing project, and I wanted to make a loop with a non-function because those can make some pretty cool shapes (EC). I made a loop, found the derivative, but Desmos is giving me hard time graphing the derivative. It seems impossible to isolate either x or y, so I'm not quite sure how to graph it, may not be possible in a program such as desmos. Here are my equations and picture of the original equation.

$$y=(x^4)/2+y^2/x$$
$$dy/dx=(2x^3-y^2x^{-2})/(1-2yx^{-1})$$

[Original Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxxMT.jpg)

Comment: If you're at all familiar with mathematica see this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25999/is-there-a-way-to-plot-the-derivative-of-an-implicit-function-in-mathematica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not impossible to isolate $y$. Notice the quadratic in $y$. Now apply the quadratic formula.

Comment: Thanks, here is a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fq2vtsxdyy) of the work/solution

Comment: @Ethan I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Isolate y with the quadratic formula:
$$y={x\pm x \sqrt{1-2x^3} \over 2}$$
Substitute into the derivative and simplify:
$$y=\frac 1 2 \pm {5x^3-1 \over 2 \sqrt{1-2x^3}}$$
Pretty fun problem!